# Heroku, NodeJs and React issue: SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'apply' of undefined or null reference

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku, mern

I have a weird issue with, I guess, polyfills. I used MERN stack for my app, and pushed to Heroku. For some reason, on my computer in Chrome I can view the website, however, on other computers I'm getting a blank page and the error in console:

```
'SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'apply' of undefined or null reference'
```

it points to this chunk of code, and, apparently, is linked to Redux:

```
return funcs.reduce(function (a, b) {
    return function () {
      return a(b.apply(undefined, arguments));
    };
  });
}
```

I imported babel-polyfill to my App.js file, even added `<script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=default,es6"></script></script>` to `index.html` but still no luck. What could be done to solve this?

**UPD: It seems that the reason is the Redux Dev Tools. I need to somehow disable it in production.**

Comment: is your computer and the other computer running same version of chrome? it is not a polyfill problem if they are, since same version of browser should support same js syntax

Comment: It is the same Version 67.0.3396.99 (Official Build) (64-bit). Also, Microsoft Edge on my computer is giving that issue as well.

Comment: it might not be related to polyfill, but session sensitive logic bug then? try it on ur computer with chrome incognito mode

Comment: Yup, same issue on incognito. Points to Redux. But I'm not using any redux state for the landing page.

Comment: Now you know the problem is related to session, you might want to try debugging in local dev mode first, with un-minified code, to find out what is actually going on.

Comment: Not sure I know what is un-minified code, and how to access the local dev mode.

Comment: run ur app in local before you push it to heroku, with sth like npm run dev. that way you can check code stack in its original form instead of functions all minified to a b c d.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176184/discussion-between-ruham-and-william-chong).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apparently, the issue was linked with the Redux DevTools that I was using. So, in redux store.js I had to change this:

```
const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  initialState,
  compose(
    applyMiddleware(...middleware),
    window._REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_ ? window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__() // Error is this line
  )
);
```

to this:

```
const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  initialState,
  compose(
    applyMiddleware(...middleware),
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ ? window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__() : f => f
  )
);
```

And everything worked.

Comment: Could you please explain the reason why this thing fixed the issue?

Comment: The line represents a function that checks whether or not the Dev Tools Extension is enabled. The error was that the function was not defined properly.