# Deployed website on Firebase but unable to view on other browsers

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-hosting

First time Firebase user. I've recently deployed my website on Firebase which works fine on Chrome on my laptop, however it doesn't show up when I use other browsers OR when I access it on another device even on Chrome. I found this particular article that had a similar issue ([Firebase hosted website won't load (but loads locally)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56264516/firebase-hosted-website-wont-load-but-loads-locally?rq=1)), tried implementing the suggested changes but still didn't work.

I use ReactJS with create-react-app, ran `npm-run-build` before running`firebase deploy` . I made sure the 'public' folder points to 'build' in the `firebase.json` file. I've attached the image of the console I get when on Opera: [Console Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zy1am.png)

I've also emptied my cache as well in case it was a cache issue.

My project is in the following github: https://github.com/tchan90/My-Pet-Infosheet

My website url is: https://my-pet-info-sheet.firebaseapp.com/

Any help or suggestions will be much appreciated!

Comment: It works now on my machine in Chrome. Doesn't work in Edge.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51388382/heroku-nodejs-and-react-issue-script5007-unable-to-get-property-apply-of-un) should solve your problem

```
window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ ? window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__() : f => f
```

Comment: Great that fixed it! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

One detail to fix (can't tell if it's the issue): you are initializing Firebase two times, and with different settings each time. Keep just one, preferably using the most recent library release, and check that the project settings are the correct ones, there is also another error that says `API key not valid`.